# (nodejs) While using the serialport library, Why is the data coming in multiple times?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a code that shows the hex data being sent by arduino.
The following is the arduino code.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  char serialPacket[9] = {0,};

  serialPacket[0] = 0x02;  // STX
  serialPacket[1] = 0x30;  // OP CODE
  serialPacket[2] = 0x04;  // LENGTH
  serialPacket[3] = 0x00;  // Sensor1
  serialPacket[4] = 0x15;  // Sensor2
  serialPacket[5] = 0x43;  // Sensor3
  serialPacket[6] = 0x32;  // Sensor4
  serialPacket[7] = 0x93;  // CRC??
  serialPacket[8] = 0x03;  // ETX

  for(uint8_t i= 0; i<sizeof(serialPacket); i++){
    Serial.write(serialPacket[i]);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

And the typescript code that outputs the received data is as follows.

```
const { SerialPort, ReadlineParser } = require('serialport')

let vdata : string[] = [];

const port = new SerialPort({
    path: 'COM3',
    baudRate: 9600,
})

port.on('open', () => console.log('Port open'))
port.on("data", (data : any) => {
    data.forEach((u: number) => {
        if (u.toString(16).length === 1) {
            vdata.push(`0x0${u.toString(16)}`)
        } else {
            vdata.push(`0x${u.toString(16)}`)
        }

    });
    console.log(vdata)
});
```

The values output to the console are as follows.

```
[ '0x02', '0x30' ]
[ '0x02', '0x30', '0x04', '0x00', '0x15', '0x43' ]
[
  '0x02', '0x30',
  '0x04', '0x00',
  '0x15', '0x43',
  '0x32', '0x93',
  '0x03'
]
```

Why is the value output multiple times??
Of the values shown in the console, only the last value is wanted to be output.

thank you.

Comment: You are adding all new info into existent array (vdata) and log entire array every time.